# Electron Field Emission through Dielectrics

Tags: electric-fields, vacuum, dielectric

While reading about some new (now older technology), it said that vacuum tubes could run on electron field emission rather than photoionization. https://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/devices/introducing-the-vacuum-transistor-a-device-made-of-nothing

It is some interesting stuff. In reading wikipedia (I know it's credibility, thus why I'm here), it says, "However, field emission can take place from solid or liquid surfaces, into vacuum, air, a fluid, or any non-conducting or **weakly conducting dielectric**." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission

So the question I have is, what would the effects be if the two electrodes were separated by a dielectric rather than a vacuum. It seems like one of the issues that NASA is having is that they are trying to reduce the probability of an electron intersecting with an atom, but if a dielectric was in the middle couldn't one compensate for that? Would electron field emission would still work? If anything you would have a constant rather than relying on a random probability and chance. In other words, the electron is jumping that gap, would there be different side effects if that gap is filled with nothing compared to a dielectric?

Edit:
@Vadim I think you figured out what I'm asking. Are field emission with tunneling via dielectrics and field emission with a vacuum able to be interchanged or would they act differently. NASA basically is creating a transistor/triode hybrid but one of the largest issues is the vacuum. Could you accomplish the same thing by replacing the vacuum with a dielectric or would it destroy the effect they are trying to achieve?

Edit 2:
First to answer my own question. Field emission with tunneling via dielectrics vs field emission through a vacuum are not exactly the same. When dealing with dielectrics if too high of a voltage is applied and too much tunneling occurs you will have achieved the breakdown voltage. Also, the electrons are still traveling through a medium and that medium may have an effect.

So using the NASA vacuum transistor as an example. Between the anode and cathode there is a vacuum. Currently they will jump through the vacuum from one to the other. (When vacuum tubes operated under high voltages with cold cathodes they often generate ionizing radiation, this may occur on a small scale here also.)

Now let's replace the vacuum with a dielectric. For the example lets use Aluminum Oxide. If too high of a voltage is used the dielectric breakdown voltage will be achieved and the logic gate will become stuck in a closed position. There also may be other effects. Near by components could possibly experience minute paramagnetic effects. Lastly, if enough energy is applied over time, the Aluminum Oxide could potentially undergo a small amount of electrolysis and become aluminum metal which would destroy it's dielectric qualities.

So for those wondering, if someone were experiment with these vacuum transistors (good luck finding equipment), could you replace the vacuum with a dielectric and still have a working component. The answer is possibly, you would need to keep the voltages lower than the breakdown voltage and longevity studies would need to be performed to confirm that the dielectric doesn't become stressed from constantly having electrons tunneled through it.

Comment: The question seems confused - mixing field emission with tunneling via dielectrics, opposing field emission and photoeffect, and mentioning unspecified NASA issue. I think it needs more clarity.

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like a transistor (or solid state diode depending ...).

Comment: @garyp Yes it would be like a transistor except that I think the physics behind it would be different than semiconductors.

Comment: @Vadim edit added to try and add clarity.